# In app purchase - Subscription - not based on Apple Id

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I understand that If a user buy something using in app purchase, it should reflect in all the devices owned by the user ( based on logged in apple id ).

But in my case I need to handle it with "our own username and not apple id". That is if user logged in to our application in multiple device, We need to handle subscription all our own.

Just to clarify, even if user logged in to two devices with same apple id but different user in our application, only the username who actually bought our subscription should get the extended access.

I believed that non-renewable subscription is what We need, but on reading a bit, I think such a subscription should reflect in all devices registered by same apple id.

So it would be great if someone could help me to select which kind of in app purchase should i choose for this scenario.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I want to implement same kind of in app purchase. So, which type you finally used? Consumable? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kind of in app purchase for this would be preferable is non consumable. In this case user don't have to buy the product again and again. Regarding your question with your own username you can maintain the record of purchase for single user in your local server. For that what you can do is while verifying the transaction receipt from your local server which you will get on every successful transaction from apple in app purchase server. For verifying the receipt you have to send the receipt to you local server in base64 encoded format then your local server will connect to the apple server you local server will verify the receipt while sending the receipt to your local server send the session id of the user to your local server if the verification of the receipt is successful then you local server will store the purchase information in local data base. If user will login in the second device also you local server will know that this user have purchase this many item and you can sink the data in all the device in which user have logged in.

Comment: Thanks Gyanendra. But I need user to purchase the subscription again after 1 year or so. I can handle all the things in my own server regarding the last date of subscription and all.  If i change user (but not the AppleID in the AppStore) I want to be able to buy another subscription. Of course the same user should not be able to pay twice but I can prevent by checking its subscription status on the server. So i should go for consumable... right?

Comment: So I basically understand it like this.. If i am going to implement one time subscription with my userInfo --- i should go for non-consumable and if its a time-based-subscription that is not auto renewable and based on my userInfo --- i should go for consumables.. so that user can buy it again and again. right?

Comment: Yes off course you should go for consumable if you want the user to be subscribed again after one year. And if you change the user but not AppleID in Appstore then user can subscribe the service for free if the service is still under subscription. So for new user you can  get new subscription if user is entering different AppleID in Appstore which is not subscribed your service.

Comment: Yes your understanding is clear regarding consumable and non consumable product.

Comment: I need user to buy a subscription again after 1 year, not get a free subscription.

Comment: can we buy consumables again with same apple id? if we can then problem is solved... I will just handle everything in my server and when subscription ends ( as per my server ) i will ask user to extent the subscription again... and that's it.

Comment: Yes you can do that with consumable.I think Apple will ask the user automatically to renew the subscription. You have to specify the subscription time in itunes connect for that product while registering the product id for in app purchase then you are done.

Comment: I facing a very similar situation and I also have a subscription for a year but I think the purchase should be a non-renewing subscription. Why you suggest a consumable? Is right to link the user account to the purchase and not the apple id?