# Link a purchase to an apple ID

Tags: ios8, in-app-purchase, nsuserdefaults

I'm implementing an in app purchase for a Non-renewing subscription in my app. I'm using an account system so I'm linking the purchase to the user account in my server. This works fine but recently I read that the purchase should be linked to an apple id. I'm a little confused because I thought you couldn't get access to an apple id. So I have some questions:

Could my app be rejected for link the purchase to an account in my system?

I read that I could use the UUID as user identifier in my server and save it in user defaults but I don't know how to identify the user if He switch devices?

If identify the user with the UUID works, I would like to control if the user logs in with the right account in my system so if he has the right UUID but a different account, He should not get access to my functionality. Is this possible or my app would be rejected for this kind of control?

Links:
[In app purchase - Subscription - not based on Apple Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462918/in-app-purchase-subscription-not-based-on-apple-id?rq=1) and [How to store and fetch the response of in-app purchase in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145421/how-to-store-and-fetch-the-response-of-in-app-purchase-in-ios/16145640#16145640)

In the apple documentation saids that you should use transactions recipes for restore in case the user switch devices but in Non-renewing subscriptions the app will be responsable for the restoration process.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH8-SW9

Comment: sorry It was non-renewing subscription.

Comment: Where you read all this stuff (Link apple id & UUID stuff)?? Can you please share the link of that?